# Get Shpping Address ZIP

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to use Shipping address zip code in this file

app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php

I want to use it in this function
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request){}

Is there any way to access the zip code there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the postcode like this:

```
var_dump($request->getDestPostcode());
```

To see all the important data of the `$request` object:

```
var_dump($request->getData());
```